# GestureRecognizers on StackLayout does not recognizes the taps/clicks in Xamarin Cross-Platform

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am new to Xamarin Platform. I have created a grid inside which I have StackLayout on which I am applying GestureRecognizers. I am deploying the app using Xamarin Live Player on Android platform.
I am using latest version of Xamarin.Forms 3.1

The tap is not getting detected/executed. Can anyone please help me on this?
I have tried following things based on various posts on google.

- Using InputTransparent="True" on StackLayout
- Removing Background color of StackLayout
- Applying GestureRecognizers on every control

None of the above resolved the problem.

Here is my code snippet:

```
<Grid x:Name="GridMain">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <!-- PANEL 1 -->

        <ContentView
        Grid.Row="0"
        IsVisible="True" BackgroundColor="White" x:Name="MainView">
        </ContentView>
        <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="Store" InputTransparent="True" HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="20" Margin="-20,-10,-20,-17" Grid.Column="0">
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <Image x:Name="baseline_store_black_24dp" IsVisible="True" Source="baseline_store_black_24dp.png" HeightRequest="22" WidthRequest="25" Margin="0,0,0,-2">
                </Image>
                <Label Margin="0" x:Name="tab_home" Text="Store" FontSize="Micro"/>
            </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

EDIT:
Here is my code behind for TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        var page = new Home();
        MainView.Content = page.Content;

    }
```

Comment: Can you try this on a physical device?

Comment: I am using it on physical device using Xamarin Live Player and not on emulator.

Comment: can you post the code behind including the Event Handler `TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped`.

Comment: I have added the code snippet in question.